# Axon4 - Multi DC active-active support

Tags: axon

**Problem statement** 
Need to implement active active replication accoross data center for **event store**. What are the available strategies with Axon framework for both - event store and projection store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection store, thus the query models, are completely in your own hands. Axon doesn't force you to choose any form or type of projection store approach.
Hence, "active active replication" is in your hands there.

Additionally, Axon Framework does not enforce a type of Event Store either, but instead allows you to choose for:

- Axon Server
- JPA
- JDBC
- Mongo

If you would choose JPA, JDBC or Mongo, it's again your responsibility to chase replication. Axon Server on the other hand had this backed in. Hence I'd suggest to take a look at that -> https://axoniq.io/

Comment: Got few follow up questions -  
1. Could not find extension for ES with JPA / JDBC at https://github.com/AxonFramework 
would appreciate if you can share some sample for the same
2. Does it support Casandra as ES  ?
3. With reference to below documentation, it seems clustering support on AxonServer is available with enterprise version only, can you please confirm
https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/operations-guide/setting-up-axon-server/axon-server-clustering

Comment: The Reference Guide had a dedicated page on the fact that JPA and JDBC are baked in to the framework - https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/event-processing/event-bus-and-event-store#event-store

And Cassandra is not supported as an Event Store is it misses the right requirements to be "exactly what you need" for an event store. I'd suggest traversing the https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/axonframework and search for Cassandra; description why it's not suited should pop up.

Comment: Thanks @Steven for your answers on point # 1, 2. Can you please confirm if clustering and managed context is available with open source version (may be partial) or its available with Enterprise versio only

Comment: Axon Server Standard edition does not employee clustering for you, thus does not give you the replication. This is an Axon Server Enterprise feature.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluated the Axon Server clustering options. It works well combine with tagging feature to achive active - active data center setup scenario